# I know we cannot make a instance of interface but this dude make it . Is this right?

Tags: kotlin

Here we return Api().userLogin(email,password) . Here Api() is a interface and can we make the instance of interface like this ??

```
class UserRepository {
suspend fun userLogin(username:String, password:String):Response<AuthResponse>
{

    return Api().userLogin(username,password)
}
}
```

This is my Interface

```
interface Api {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
suspend fun userLogin(
        @Field("email")
        username:String,

        @Field("password")
        password:String
):Response<AuthResponse>

companion object
{
    operator fun invoke():Api
    {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.simplifiedcoding.in/course-apis/mvvm/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(Api::class.java)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where's definition for `MyApi`?

Comment: sorry its Api  not MyApi

Answer (score 2):

One of the operators we can overload in Kotlin is the [`invoke` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#invoke-operator), which is called when we "call" an instance as though it's a function. For instance, we could define

```
class Foo {
  operator fun invoke() {
    println("Hi")
  }
}
```

and then call this with

```
val myFoo = Foo()
myFoo() # Calls myFoo.invoke()
```

Now, you have correctly pointed out that interfaces don't have constructors. As such, `Api()` cannot be a constructor call. The name `Api` refers to an interface as well as its companion object, and we're calling `invoke` on the companion object. So `Api()` in your code is equivalent to `Api.invoke()`, a method call on the companion object `Api` which, based on the code you've shown, uses `Retrofit.Builder()` to construct a concrete instance of the `Api` interface.

Comment: how we can access the userlogin function like this Api().userLogin(username,password) although it is not a invoke function nor a companion object ??

Comment: In your code example, it looks like `userLogin` is the only method defined on the `Api` interface. `Api().userLogin(...)` is equivalent to `Api.invoke().userLogin(...)`. `Api.invoke()` is returning an `Api` instance